# 'Published To' Information

Tags: 2011, core-service

How can I get the information found on the 'Published to' tab via Core Service?

I can get 'Used In' and 'Uses' no problem, but can't seem to track down 'Published to' information.

Help greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `client.GetListPublishInfo` method.

For example, if you wanted to spit out the name of all the Publication Targets that a page is published to, you could do the following:

```
PublishInfoData[] pubInfo = client.GetListPublishInfo("tcm:144-60576-64");
foreach (PublishInfoData info in pubInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(info.PublicationTarget.Title);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: As long as you *know* the difference between publication target, target type, and publication, all is forgivable. ;-)